# Should separating pull apart Challah rolls be considered a forbidden act of completion?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work, challah-shabbat-bread

I have heard many people state that using Challah* rolls that are baked in one unit to be pulled apart might be a problem for making Leḥem** Mishneh on Shabbath. In fact, there are rolls that are sold in my local supermarket that have a sticker on the outside of the bag that says something to the effect of, "Ask your rabbi about Lechem*** Mishneh."

I've heard some people state that, in fact, it is not a problem from that perspective, since the rolls are meant to be used separately.

My question, though, is that if the latter opinion is correct, wouldn't that make it an even *bigger* problem, namely completing the creation of some product, **or does this not apply to food?**

CYLOR, of course.

Comment: *I know I'm deviating from my adopted transliteration scheme. But my childhood got the best of me in this one. I can't spell Challah any other way.

Comment: **I'm being internally inconsistent, I know.

Comment: ***I'm using their spelling.

Comment: Very related, but not a dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/what-is-the-status-of-a-pull-apart-challah-for-lechem-mishneh

Comment: Thanks, @IsaacMoses. I didn't see it pop up when I was writing my question.

Comment: One idea to look at- can the rolls be used as lechem mishne while they are attached (seems so), and if that is the case, would makke b'patish apply just because you decided to separate them?

Comment: The same question could apply to breaking the squares of a Hershey's bar.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't see how that's the same. The Hershey bar is meant to be consumed however the customer likes, either one square at a time or all at once, or in bites completely disregarding the squares. But the rolls are meant to be pulled apart and used individually.

Comment: @SethJ Couldn't you slice the pull-apart-challah without first pulling apart if you wanted slices too?

Comment: @DoubleAA, of course you could - but the reason it was made as rolls in the first place was for the purpose of having multiple rolls. Mah SheEin Ken beHershey bars.

Comment: Makeh b'patish by food?!? I will let others post the mareh makomos -- no strength right now. Maybe later...

Comment: @Yehoshua, I did end with, "or does this not apply to food?"

Comment: @SethJ Many mareh makomos on this many I'll get to it...

Comment: @SethJ See Gemorah Shabbos Daf 50b with Rashi and Tosfos. Tehillah L'David Siman 318 Sif-Katan 20 and what he brings from the Rashba that asks on Rashi. See ShuT Maharsham Chelek Alef Siman 164, See Yabia Omer Chelek Ches OC Siman 35.) See Shevat HaKahasi (from R' Shammai Gross Shlit"a) in Chelek Vav Siman 165. See Minchas Chinnuch in B'Mosach HaShabbos Melachos Ofeh Sif-Katan 8. See ShuT Bar Yitzchak OC Siman 13 Anaf 8 d"h "v'nidan"). See Shitas Yerushalmi in regards to makeh b'patish in Ochlin SHabbos Daf 48b and viter. See also M"B Siman 319 Sif-Katan 22.

Comment: @Yehoshua, thanks. I'll have to remember to look at those later (can't right now).

Comment: @Matt, the question isn't about the sticker. It's about whether or not there's a bigger problem that's not addressed by the sticker.

Comment: @SethJ actually I just reread your question and realized that I misunderstood it. Sorry, I'm deleting my other comments now

Comment: @Matt, it turns out that I recently heard a Shi'ur in which it was expressed very clearly that there is no such Halachah vis a vis food. However, that was a tangent from the main point. A sourced answer would still be helpful to me. Your comments aren't really germane to the question. No offense.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Yitzchak Zilberstein (Chashukei Chemed to Beitzah 32a) rules that according to all opinions, one may separate challahs that have been baked together, since there is no concept of Makeh Bepatish in foods:

> ‏ שאלה: הוציאו מהתנור שתי לחמניות מחוברות, ובשבת רוצה לבצוע ולברך עליהם, האם מותר להפרידם, כדי לקיים לחם משנה?

> ‏ תשובה נחלקו רבותינו אם צריך להפריד את החלות כדי לקיים מצוות לחם משנה, בספר מנחת שבת (בסוף ההשמטות לסימן עז) הביא את דברי השואל ומשיב (מהדו"ק ח"א סוף סימן קסז) שכתב ששני חלות שנדבקו באפיה, כיון שדעתו להפרישם זה מזה, אינן חיבור, ויוצא ידי חובת לחם משנה גם בהיותם דבוקים, מאידך בארחות חיים כתב שהמהרש"ם חולק עליו וס"ל דיש להפרידם, וטעמו מפני שאם אין צריך להפרידם, ממילא אין דעתו להפרידם ונחשבים כאחת, יעו"ש.

> ‏ ויש להסתפק לדעת הפוסקים שצריך להפריד, האם מותר להפרידם בשבת, או שיש בזה איסור של מתקן מנא.

> ‏  דהנה נחלקו רבותינו האם מותר להפריד גביעי לבן בשבת, בשלחן שלמה (סימן שיד ס"ט עמ' רה) התיר, וכתב שאין זה דומה למה שאסור להפריד כוסות ונרות הדבקים יחד (כמבואר ברמב"ם פ"ד מיו"ט ה"ח) שהתם הנרות דבוקים לכל ארכם ונראים ככלי אחד, ובכה"ג אסור להפרידם והרי זה כמתקן כלי, שמכלי אחד עשה ב' כלים, ודמי למבואר בביצה דף לב ע"א דאסור לחתוך פתילה או נר לשנים, דמתקן מנא, משא"כ בגביעי הלבן כל גביע עומד בפני עצמו, והם ניכרים ומופרדים, ודומים לב' גביעים, רק כדי שיהיה קל למוכרם, משאירים אותם מחוברים למעלה, ואין בהפרדתם משום תיקון כלי, יעו"ש.

> ‏ מאידך בספר ארחות שבת (פי"א הערה ס) הביא את דעת מו"ח מרן הגרי"ש אלישיב זצ"ל לאסור זאת משום מכה בפטיש, משום שבהפרדת הגביעים מגיע הגביע לצורתו הרצויה.
>  ונראה דגם לדעת מו"ח זצ"ל אין בהפרדת הלחמניות איסור, משום שאין מכה בפטיש באוכלים, וכמבואר בביאור הלכה (סימן שיח ס"ד ד"ה בהדחתן) וז"ל: היוצא מדברנו דענין מכה בפטיש בדבר אוכל, הוא דבר חדש, שלא נמצא בפוסקים ואדרבה יש כמה סתירות ועל כן אין להחמיר.:

Answer (score 2):

The question of Makah B'Patish comes into play regarding opening bottles, cans and packages on Shabbos. Even by these items there is a dispute amongst the Poskim whether this is allowed as it may already be a Kli prior to opening them or not allowed. Even among those that do not allow opening these on Shabbos there are those that hold if you immediately use the contents and dispose of the container then you are not using it as a Kli and you may. I have not seen any Poskim having concerns regarding breaking apart Challa rolls which leads me to believe that there is no issue of Makah B'Patish over here.

Comment: What does everything but your last sentence have to with the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA He was showing you how much he has seen so you would understand the significance of his having not seen :)