# Food that become ossur "c'dei klipah" -- removing on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, borer-separating

A food that become ossur "c'dei klipah" (a "peels worth") from some sort of issur (prohibited food) is one allowed to remove the "klipah" on Shabbos? Is this an issue of borer (separating?) Are there any poskim that speak about this particular case (beside from any answer where one may draw a similarity from this case to another.)

***Note:*** One could ask if there perhaps is a problem of "fixing" the food. There is already much discussion about makeh b'patish b'ochel. However I'm more asking about the problem of borer in this case.

Comment: **ahem** related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13220/should-separating-pull-apart-challah-rolls-be-considered-a-forbidden-act-of-comp#comment67468_13220

Comment: @SethJ In terms of makeh b'patish I know there is no problem (per the mareh makomos.) However if I didn't add that into the question I know I would be attacked "why not ask if it's a problem of makeh b'patish"

Comment: @SethJ edited to reflect what I am really asking however not skipping over that point.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that it is not Borer (separating) in accordance to how SA Horav explains in Hilcos YT (500:18) the reason why Nikkur (separating the forbidden fats and veins from an animal) is permitted on Yom Tov, thogh it may appear like Borer (separating), is because really it's all one Min (species) with the meat it's just that the Torah forbade that part of the one Min and the prohibition of Borer is by two (or more) Minim. That same logic could apply by Issur Kelipah.