# Married women uncovering their hair in the presence of gentiles

Tags: halacha, gentiles, women, marriage, hair-covering

Is there a halachic difference of a married women covering her hair in the presence of Jews or Gentiles? Even if you hold like the  chasam sofer who says that it's  Deoraisa?

Answer (score 2):

Well if she's around Jews *and* uncovered hair is treated as *ervah*, then she'd be stopping any nearby Jews from praying or saying any brachos.

Generally it's assumed that the obligation of married women to cover is independent of the *ervah* status, so no it wouldn't make a difference.

The Gemara in Kesubos describes the prohibition as being "in public", and something like a courtyard (or in modern-day terms, walking from her apartment to another one inside the building) may not be "in public." But I'm not aware of any source distinguishing between Jews and non-Jews watching.

Comment: Shalom, only nearby male Jews would have a problem. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56273/759