# Does a woman have to dress tzniut in front of other women

Tags: halacha, women, clothing, tznius-modesty, even-haezer

According to Halacha, is there a requirement for a woman to dress tzniut around other women (with no men present)?

Or, since there are no men around, is she permitted to dress in what would otherwise be prohibited in public?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56273/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69816/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this question asked in relation to women-only gyms. Can women dress in sport pants when there is no man around?

Writing in [Halichos bas Yisrael](https://menuchapublishers.com/products/halichos-bas-yisrael-volumes-i-ii), R Yitzchak Yaacov Fuchs writes (p. 103 in the 1-volume edition) that

> A woman may wear women's pants for exercising if no men are present

In [Reclaiming Dignity](https://mosaicapress.com/product/reclaiming-dignity/), R Anthony Manning writes at length that the specific application of the laws of *tzniut* are very context-dependent. Referring specifically to your question he writes (p. 243) **it might be entirely *tzanua* for a young woman sitting at home with a close friend to remove her hair covering**, but not appropriate for a elderly *rebbetzin* to do so with a younger woman from her community. In other words, it is halachically permissing but not always wise.