# One Challah or Two?

Tags: halacha, number, challah-shabbat-bread

If two challahs are braided and baked together on one pan, and before they are completely baked, they have stuck together, do I have one challah or two?  i.e. can I separate them and still have two challahs for lechem mishneh?

The same question would apply to store-bought challah rolls that come in a six pack where all six are stuck together.

Comment: related (and the question there kind of answers this one): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/what-is-the-status-of-a-pull-apart-challah-for-lechem-mishneh

Comment: See Tevul Yom 1:1

Comment: Possibly also relevant: Pesachim 48b, "ככרות של בבל שנושכות זו מזו".

Comment: This was discussed, with regard to matzos backed in a large sheet, on (IIRC) Hirhurim. Will search.

Answer (score 1):

You have two *challot*.

R Simcha Bunim Cohen writes in [The radiance of Shabbos](https://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=RADH) (p. 77)

> **Loaves that become attached during baking may be separated and are
> still considered whole for the purpose of *lechem mishne***

In the footnote he refers to [Machatzit Hashekel 174:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Machatzit_HaShekel_on_Orach_Chayim.274.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Similarly Shmirat Shabbat KeHilchata 55:4:6 writes

> **Two loaves which became stuck together whilst being baked may be used
> as *lechem mishneh***, even if they are still attached to each other.
>
> However there is a view which disputes this and holds that one must
> first separate them.
>
> In the event that one separates them from each other, and they remain
> whole, they are indeed considered whole loaves, even if one can tell
> they were joined together. Where part of one loaf remains stuck to the
> other, it is well to remove the piece, so that the loaf to which it is
> stuck should indeed look whole.

Comment: It sounds from his wording like this is only where the attachment was incidental. "Pull apart challa" loaves would not be included